# Not sure of the name.. (bit field)

Tags: terminology

I'm not sure what the name of this is called, so I had no idea what to call it.

it's when people use a number to type something, but it's somewhat binary based: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, etc

for example: 1 = apples, 2 = oranges, 4 = bananas then 3 = apples and oranges, 7 = apples, oranges and bananas.

What is this called?

Comment: You're talking about using numbers to represent sets by treating each bit position as indicator of an item's presence in a set instance, right?

Comment: Love the quick responses. Thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many different terms, but I would call that a **bit field**.  If you're using Java there is a class for this called `BitSet`.

I've also heard it called **bit flags**.

Answer (score 1):

Bit fields aka Bit flags?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field

Answer (score 1):

I think it is (or similar to) bit array. So each bit stores the state of something. In this case whether this fruit is available or not.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a bit flag, or bit field.